# Export Tomcat Catalina Logs to external server

Tags: java, android, tomcat, logging

I am using Tomcat 7.x as my web server and I am using java.util.logging and JULI for logging. This Tomcat server is hosted an Amazon EC2 instance which runs Ubuntu.

**The Problem** is whenever I wish to see the logs (in catalina.log file) I have go through a very time consuming process of copying, chowing and then downloading the files to my local machine before I can see them. (I can use utilities like nano or vi but they do not help much)

**My Question** Can I automatically exports the logs to some external server and view them straight away. Some thing similar to Bugsense for ACRA reports in Android.

Comment: it is much more convenient to use less command to view logs files. Even more convenient than notepad or something similar. You just need to used to. Everything you need: scroll page up/down, scroll cursor and search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a servlet to run in Tomcat to read the logs and display them in your web browser.  Or if the file is large, zip it up and allow you to download it.

Use the environment variable `catalina.base` to determine the base directory and then gather up logs/catalina.log.

[update]

The best approach would depend on your background. If you are comfortable doing a basic, no-frills servlet, start with `the simplest design that could possibly work` such as:

```
class LogServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      File logFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "logs/catalina.log");
      String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(logFile);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
      out.println(contents);
   }
}
```

I am using commons-io to simplify reading the log file, but otherwise it's just the Java servlet framework.

Comment: +1, Idea seems workable to me, any libraries, blog or suggestion how to go about doing it.

Comment: See update.  We used the servlet approach above to do something similar.

Comment: I will implement it. Any suggested libraries.

Comment: Ok, I will keep this question open for one more days looking for other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

rsync then periodically use a cron job on the server you want or use some tool like collectd.

Answer (score 0):

You could use logstash or fluentd to stream the logs and load into your prefered target, say Elastic Search. You could visualize or search through the logs from elasticsearch using visualization tools like Kibana or Graylog

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)