# Tomcat Servlet not showing Log out

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to create a servlet which will output Tomcat Logs on the browser from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519734/932307) example

```
File logFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "logs/catalina.log");
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(logFile);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
out.println(contents);
```

This is working fine but I am trying to change the code to get the output of *catalina.2012-11-29.log*. The changed code is below

```
Log.log(Level.OFF, "Inside doGet of LogServlet");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//get current date time with Date()
Date date = new Date();
Log.log(Level.INFO, "Date = {0}", dateFormat.format(date));
String fileName = "logs/catalina." + dateFormat.format(date) + ".log";
Log.log(Level.INFO, "fileName = {0}", fileName);
Log.log(Level.INFO, "System.getProperty(catalina.base) = {0}", System.getProperty("catalina.base"));
File logFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), fileName);
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(logFile);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream());
out.println(contents);
```

But this code does not work instead the browser window remains empty. I could not figure out why it is not working?

Comment: does catalina.2012-11-29.log really exists and is non empty?

Comment: Yes, I have chked it exists and is not empty.

Comment: Ok, are you sure there are no exceptions thrown from your second snippet? for e.g. by FileUtils.readFileToString call? Just to be sure, log logFile.exists() result somewhere and check that its true. If you see that it is true, the problem is not with your snippet. it is somewhere outside of this snippet.

Comment: @amol The value is "true", where do you imagine error possible be?